# MongoDB Data Range Filter Subcollection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get the values of a subcollection base on a data range filter. However when I do the filtering I am getting all the values of the collection.

For example for the following data I want to obtain only the values for dates in range `2019-01-01` to `2019-12-31`

```
[
  {
    symbol: "sensor1",
    data: [
      {
        date: ISODate("2017-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
        value: 2.45,
        
      },
      {
        date: ISODate("2019-11-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
        value: 2.2444
      },
      {
        date: ISODate("2019-12-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
        value: 2.5,
        
      },
      {
        date: ISODate("2020-01-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
        value: 2.461,
        
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Any recomendation?
Thanks!

Here is the playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/UGpvgzjoFCi

Answer (score 1):

you can do an aggregation with `$project` and `$filter`.
`$filter` can be used on the array to filter out the dates based on a condition.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      symbol: "sensor1"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "symbol": 1,  //show symbol in final result
      "_id": 0,     //hide _id in final result
      "data": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "d",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$$d.date",
                  ISODate("2019-01-01")
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$$d.date",
                  ISODate("2020-12-31")
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CL529Gs8ph2)

Comment: Thanks! Another solution I was working now is the following:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/jVgpHVZOjT9

It may be a little more complicated

Comment: yeah aggregation is super powerful